# pyspark `substr' without length

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way, in pyspark, to perform the `substr` function on a DataFrame column, without specifying the length? Namely, something like `df["my-col"].substr(begin)`.

Comment: what is begin here?

Comment: So, if a string is `Alex Shtof` then `df["my-col"].substr(3)` should return `ex Shtof`? Basically, the entire string right from the `begin`! Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure why this function is not exposed as api in `pysaprk.sql.functions` module.

`SparkSQL` supports the `substring` function without defining len argument `substring(str, pos, len)`

You can use it with `expr` api of `functions` module like below to achieve same:

```
df.withColumn('substr_name', f.expr("substring(name, 2)")).show()
+----------+---+-----------+
|      name| id|substr_name|
+----------+---+-----------+
|Alex Shtof|  1|  lex Shtof|
|      SMaZ|  2|        MaZ|
+----------+---+-----------+
```

**How spark is doing it internally :**

Now if you see `physical plan` of above statement then will notice that if we don't pass `len` then *spark will automatically add 2147483647*.

As @pault said in comment, 2147483647 is the maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer (2^31 -1).

```
df.withColumn('substr_name', f.expr("substring(name, 2)")).explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [name#140, id#141L, substring(name#140, 2, 2147483647) AS substr_name#169]
+- Scan ExistingRDD[name#140,id#141L] --> 2147483647 is automatically added
```

In `substring` api implementation of `functions` module, it expect us to explicitly pass length. If you want then you can give any higher number in `len` which can cover max lengths of your column.

```
df.withColumn('substr_name', f.substring('name', 2, 100)).show()
+----------+---+-----------+
|      name| id|substr_name|
+----------+---+-----------+
|Alex Shtof|  1|  lex Shtof|
|      SMaZ|  2|        MaZ|
+----------+---+-----------+

>>> df.withColumn('substr_name', f.substring('name', 2, 100)).explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [name#140, id#141L, substring(name#140, 2, 100) AS substr_name#189]
+- Scan ExistingRDD[name#140,id#141L] --> 100 is what we passed
```

Comment: [2147483647 is the maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647). This is the default value for the `len` parameter in spark-sql, but it seems that it wasn't set in the API version.

Comment: @pault : Exactly , Let me add this in ans. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the objective is to make a substring from a position given by a parameter `begin` to the end of the string, then you can do it as follows:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

l = [(1, 'Prague'), (2, 'New York')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['id', 'city'])

begin = 2

l = (f.length('city') - f.lit(begin) + 1)
(
  df
  .withColumn('substr', f.col('city').substr(f.lit(begin), l))
).show()

+---+--------+-------+
| id|    city| substr|
+---+--------+-------+
|  1|  Prague|  rague|
|  2|New York|ew York|
+---+--------+-------+
```

Comment: This is superior to using a `udf`, but just as a note any length that's longer than the string would work. So you don't have to compute `l`. Simply using the length of the string would be sufficient: `f.col('city').substr(f.lit(begin), f.length('city'))`, or a really big number:  `f.col('city').substr(f.lit(begin), f.lit(1000000))`

Answer (score 0):

I'd create udf.

```py
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([('Alice', 23), ('Brian', 25)], schema=["name", "age"])
>>> df.show()
+-----+---+
| name|age|
+-----+---+
|Alice| 23|
|Brian| 25|
+-----+---+

>>> @F.udf(returnType=StringType())
... def substr_udf(col):
...    return str(col)[2:]


>>> df = df.withColumn('substr', substr_udf('name'))
>>> df.show()
+-----+---+------+
| name|age|substr|
+-----+---+------+
|Alice| 23|   ice|
|Brian| 25|   ian|
+-----+---+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

No we need to specify the both parameters pos and len
BUt do make sure that both should be of same type other wise it will give error.

> Error: Column not iterable.

You can do in this way:

```
df = df.withColumn("new", F.col("previous").substr(F.lit(5), F.length("previous")-5))
```